# GridLayout not showing on devices

Tags: xamarin, android-gridlayout

I've this problem using GridLayout, tested on two Samsung devices.
This is an excerpt from the layout:

```
    <GridLayout
        a:layout_width="0dp"
        a:layout_weight="2"
        a:layout_height="match_parent"
        a:rowCount="5"
        a:columnCount="4">
        <TextView
            a:id="@+id/tvDescentsFemaleCount"
            style="@style/dataPanelControlLabels"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="0"
            a:layout_column="0"
            a:layout_columnWeight="3"
            a:layout_columnSpan="3"
            a:text="@string/pnlVisitDescentsFemaleDescentNumber" />
        <Button
            a:id="@+id/bDescentsFemaleCount"
            style="@style/dataButton"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="1"
            a:layout_column="0"
            a:layout_columnWeight="3"
            a:layout_columnSpan="3"
            a:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            a:layout_marginRight="3dp" />
        <ImageView
            a:id="@+id/ivDescentsMoveLeft"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="1"
            a:layout_column="3"
            a:layout_columnWeight="1"
            a:src="@drawable/freccia_indietro"
            a:adjustViewBounds="true"
            a:scaleType="centerInside" />
        <TextView
            a:id="@+id/tvDescentsMaleCount"
            style="@style/dataPanelControlLabels"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="2"
            a:layout_column="0"
            a:layout_columnSpan="3"
            a:layout_columnWeight="3"
            a:text="@string/pnlVisitDescentsMaleDescentNumber" />
        <Button
            a:id="@+id/bDescentsMaleCount"
            style="@style/dataButton"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="3"
            a:layout_column="0"
            a:layout_columnSpan="3"
            a:layout_columnWeight="3"
            a:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            a:layout_marginRight="3dp" />
        <ImageView
            a:id="@+id/ivDescentsMoveRight"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="3"
            a:layout_column="3"
            a:layout_columnWeight="1"
            a:src="@drawable/freccia_avanti"
            a:adjustViewBounds="true"
            a:scaleType="centerInside" />
        <ImageView
            a:id="@+id/ivDescentsAdd"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="4"
            a:layout_column="0"
            a:layout_columnWeight="1"
            a:layout_margin="3dp"
            a:src="@drawable/add"
            a:adjustViewBounds="true"
            a:scaleType="centerInside"
            a:padding="6dp" />
        <ImageView
            a:id="@+id/ivDescentsRemove"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_columnWeight="1"
            a:layout_row="4"
            a:layout_column="1"
            a:layout_margin="3dp"
            a:padding="6dp"
            a:src="@drawable/meno"
            a:adjustViewBounds="true"
            a:scaleType="centerInside" />
        <ToggleButton
            a:id="@+id/tbDescentsFemaleSelect"
            style="@style/toggleButtonPv"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="4"
            a:layout_column="2"
            a:layout_columnWeight="1"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_margin="3dp"
            a:textOn="@string/pnlVisitDescentsFemaleShort"
            a:textOff="@string/pnlVisitDescentsFemaleShort"
            a:padding="4dp" />
        <ToggleButton
            a:id="@+id/tbDescentsMaleSelect"
            style="@style/toggleButtonPv"
            a:layout_width="0dp"
            a:layout_row="4"
            a:layout_column="3"
            a:layout_columnWeight="1"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_margin="3dp"
            a:textOn="@string/pnlVisitDescentsMaleShort"
            a:textOff="@string/pnlVisitDescentsMaleShort"
            a:padding="4dp" />
    </GridLayout>
```

On the complete layout there is another GridLayout, where the only difference is the absence of the a:layout_columnSpan attribute (I've shortened the classic namespace declaration from xmlns:android... to xlmns:a...).
This is the less-significant screenshot from my PC designer :
[image: Screenshot from VS2017 designer]

This is the screenshot from an SM-T535, API level 21 Samsung tablet :
[image: SM-T535 screenshot]
On the upper left corner there is a GridLayout, on the middle right there is an android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout. I've left the layout limits only to show how the widgets are rendered.

This is the screenshot from an SM-T585, API level 24 Samsung tablet:
[image: SM-T585 screenshot n. 1]
The GridLayout is rendered correctly, whereas the android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout on the right is rendered almost in the same way.

This is the screenshot from the same SM-T585, where all the two widgets are the standard GridLayout:
[image]

Please note also the switch bank under the GridLayout on the right; they are android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat, because originally I was porting the app on a GT-N800 Samsung tablet, and the standard Switch widget was not so customizable. In the Activity code I'm substituting the standard typeface with a font from an asset. Only on the SM-T585 the font is shown correctly.
The activity inherits from Activity, but inheriting from AppCompatActivity doesn't change a single pixel.
The entire project is a Xamarin app (I'm porting the same app developed for IOS, so I've to recycle a great part of the code), and the IDE is VS2017 Community edition.
The same layout (GridLayout widgets) works correctly on a Nexus 7, although the screen is too small.
Any suggestion appreciated.
Thanks.

Rodolfo.

Comment: Sorry for indicating the wrong tablet model codes.... The SM-T585 is actually a SM-T580, and the GT-N800 is a GT-N8000.

Comment: For now I've reverted to a more classic (and working) solution based on a grid composed of LinearLayouts.